# react native Generating Signed APK

Tags: android, react-native, apk, signed-apk

I am trying to generate apk for releasing on Google play. I am following these steps https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Step 1) I ran this command

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

It asked me question which I answered and got the my-release-key.keystore file generated

I placed the my-release-key.keystore file under the android/app directory in your project folder.

Now it says: 
Edit the file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and add the following (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key password),

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias 
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***** 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Now there was no file previously in /root/.gradle/gradle.properties so i created a new file and added the above 4 constant and there values.
Also it tells (replace ***** with the correct keystore password, alias and key password )

This step is most confusing for me, as there is no ***** in alias field. And when I generated my-release-key.keystore file I din't get any alias

So what I should put in place of my-key-alias ?

What is basically my-key-alias?

other than the 2 passwords i entered, the keytool command generated something like this

```
CO=Dev Abhi, OP=The Awesome Coder, L=The Awesome Coder, M=Delhi, SP=Delhi, M=IN
```

are the above the alisa?

so do i need to replace things like

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-release-key.keystore 
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=CO=Dev Abhi, OP=The Awesome Coder, L=The Awesome Coder, M=Delhi, SP=Delhi, M=IN 
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=password1
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=password2
```

and also Is the real path for ~/.gradle/gradle.properties  /root/.gradle/gradle.properties ??

Comment: where did you get MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD? while generating keystore its only asked for keystore password!

Comment: `keytool` defaults to PKCS12 now, which does not seem to require password for the key. To generate password for the key, the storetype has to be set as `jks`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49599630/9723036

Answer (score 3):

Finally I was able to generate signed apk. So, the thing I was missing -

when you fire the command

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

after option -alias we mention any name/term 'my-key-alias'. that's actually what we need to remember and will have to use same term like this in later step

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
```

rest of the things are as per documentation. But, I still feel that **generating signed apk** part could have been made more easy to understand bay react native team. If any one face this same issue please get in touch via http://customphpscript.com

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this will help you, but I was having the exact same issue. My problem ended up being that the file I was editing `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` isn't the file in your project directory but the one in the root directory of your operating system. Once I moved the variables to that location, I was able to generate a signed apk!