# Keytool do not ask for alias password

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to generate a keystore file to sign my React Native Android app and publish it to Play Store.

I'm trying to do it as described in this docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html. Basically, I'm running the following in the terminal: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`.

This command asks for the keystore password, but not for alias password. I need the alias password to setup my App Center build and to sign as described in the docs above. Can't understand where's is it stored.

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here. Please help anyone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found a solution. The reason was that my keytool version generates PKCS12 keystore, non JKS. As it says `Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores.`

So I was able to generate a JKS file by passing `-storetype jks` parameter (and it asked for two passwords). And now it says `The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using...`

Comment: Please tell me what is the solution? How to generate signed apk with expo without key password?